# Tracking location of Android devices

Tags: android, maps, android-location

I am developing a project which is based on android, with which I can track location of installed users in real time.i.e all those people who will install my app will allow their location to be tracked by their friends when needed,based on permissions given to contacts.
I am familiar with java and android programming. I want to know how to start that what all things i need to use. Any brief description on the working methodology of such apps will be very helpful to me.For reference my concept is something similar to this app
https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.nplay.funa  thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint :- Use [Firebase](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/) real time database with [Google Location API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/location).

Comment: Hello hitesh... If u r okay then can we please further discuss this on mail or social media as i have few questions and i vl be really v thankful if u cud provide me some guidance...